# Testing Custom Gradle Plugins: Providing Configuration Data

Tags: gradle

I am trying to test a custom Gradle plugin that is configured via an Extension object that would normally be present in the build.gradle file.

For example, my build.gradle would normally look something like this:

```
{
  apply plugin: 'foobarConfigurator'

  [... stuff ...]

  foobarConfig {
    bar = 'boop'
    baz = 'baap'
    bot = 'faab'
  }

  [... stuff ...]
}
```

In my custom plugin class I have code that does this in the apply method:

```
def config = project.extensions.create('foobarConfig', FooBarConfig)
```

It's unclear to me how in a JUnit test I should write my test methods so that I can provide and test for different configuration values in a foobarConfiguration in a Project instance created by the ProjectBuilder class.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to write a JUnit test for your extension, you can simply create an instance and configure it programmatically:

```
class FooBarConfigTest {

    private FooBarConfig fooBarConfig

    @Before
    public void before() {
        fooBarConfig = new FooBarConfig()
    }

    @Test
    public void example() {
        fooBarConfig.bar = 'boop'
        assertEquals("expectedIfBarIsBoop", fooBarConfig.someMethod())
    }

}
```

On the other hand, to test the plugin itself, you can use a ProjectBuilder and find the extension by type:

```
class MyPluginTest {

    private MyPlugin plugin
    private Project project

    @Before
    public void before() {
        project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
        plugin = new MyPlugin()
        plugin.apply(project)
    }

    @Test
    public void example() {
        FooBarConfig foobarConfig = project.extensions.findByType(FooBarConfig)
        assertNotNull(foobarConfig)
        foobarConfig.bar = 'boop'
    }

}
```